# Factorization of a Block Matrix

Tags: matrices

Cosider the following block matrices

\begin{equation}
[A]=\begin{bmatrix} [A_{11}] & [A_{12}] & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\  [A_{21}] & [A_{22}] & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  \\  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
[B]=\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0&0&0& \cdots \\ 0 & [B_{11}] & [B_{12}] & 0 & \cdots \\  0 & [B_{21}] & [B_{22}] & 0 & \cdots \\    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  \\  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
[C]=\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0&0&0& \cdots \\ 0 &0&0&0& \cdots \\ 0&0 & [C_{11}] & [C_{12}] &  \cdots \\ 0& 0 & [C_{21}] & [C_{22}] & \cdots \\  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

which are all symmetric and overlap. The matrix $[M_i]$ is a linear combination of them, as
\begin{equation}
[M_i] = a_i [A] + b_i [B]+c_i [C]+\cdots
\end{equation}
in which $a_i$, $b_i$, and $c_i$ are constants.

What is the most efficient way to factorize $[M_i]$ for different values of $a_i$, $b_i$, and $c_i$? How about $[M_i]^{-1}$?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you understand under "factorize"? $LU$ decomposition? SVD?

Comment: I finally want to solve $[M_i]x=b$. Since $[M_i]$ is symmetric (and positive definite), my initial choice would be the Cholesky decomposition.